# Is it possible to find all java jars from one place

Tags: java, jar

where to find jar files required for all Java EE level websites like

All jars for spring , hibernate , logging , maven etc.

could not find it

EDIT:

I want  something like library.zip file where all the required jars may be 
hibernate , spring , mysql , oracle , velocity are in one file so that i can use same every where so that i don't need to repeat  that step again again. Maven is option but i want other option as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spring jars

- http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/spring/

The hibernate jars can be found here. Search for hibernate if necessary

- https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/index.html#nexus-search;quick~hibernate

Answer (score 1):

Use maven to build your application and you do not have to ask such questions. Maven does the work for you: it downloads all required dependencies.

Comment: but i want to do everything by me . also something if i don't have internet then maven causes problem

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend:

I found this list for spring on a page found using search string "all jars files required for spring"

```
* spring-aop.jar
* spring-beans.jar
* spring-context.jar
* spring-context-support.jar
* spring-core.jar
* spring-jdbc.jar
* spring-jms.jar
* spring-orm.jar
* spring-test.jar
* spring-tx.jar
* spring-web.jar
* spring-webmvc.jar
* spring-webmvc-portlet.jar
* spring-webmvc-struts.jar
```

rinse and repeat....